# Number of real $x$ satisfying the trigo equation $1+\sin 2x=\sin x+\sin^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

Number of real $x$ satisfying the trigo equation $1+\sin 2x=\sin x+\sin^2 x$ in $x\in(0,2\pi)$

solution i try $1+\sin 2x =\sin x+\sin^2 x$

$5+4\sin 2x=4\sin^2 x+4\sin x+1$

$5+\sin 2x=(2\sin x+1)^2$ How i solve it after that point

Comment: At some point one needs to put $\sin(2x)$ in terms of just $\sin x$ [This will involve a $\pm$ and a squareroot...]

Comment: Just for fun http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1+%3D+sin%5E2+x+%2B+sin+x+-+sin(2x).

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember the double angle formulas? I don't see you using that.

Now, consider writing it all again using this fact. I've attached my work that get you to a point where you need to reason out the angles, and I've hidden it so you can at least work out some more using the double angle formula! :)

> $$ 1 + \sin(2x) = \sin(x) + \sin^2(x)\\1 + 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin^2(x) + \sin(x)\\ 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin^2(x) - 1 + \sin(x)\\ 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = -\cos^2(x) + \sin(x)\\ 2\sin(x)\cos(x) + \cos^2(x) = \sin(x)\\ 2\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \tan(x)\\ 2 + \cot(x) = \tan(x)\csc(x)\\ 2 + \cot(x) = \sec(x)\\ 2 = \sec(x) - \cot(x)\\ 2 = \frac{1}{\cos(x)} - \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} $$

And from there you should be able to reason out the angles which satisfy that equality.

Edit: Maybe you wrote the problem down wrong for us?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $y = \sin x$

$$1 + 2y\sqrt{1-y^2} = y + y^2 $$

$$2y\sqrt{1-y^2} = (y + y^2 -1) \implies 4y^2(1-y^2) = (y+ y^2 -1)^2$$

Simplifying, we get $5y^4 + 2y^3 - 5y^2 -2y + 1 = 0$

Solve somehow to get $y = 0.311$ or $y = 0.913$ and so $x = 0.316$ or $x = 1.15$

Comment: The question only asks for the number of solutions, so once you have the quartic $f$, you can, for example, take the derivative and solve that cubic to find that there are two local extrema above $y=0$ and one below. But $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)>0$, so there must be two real solutions between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: There are problems with this. When you replace $\cos(x)$ with $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ you are assuming $\cos(x)$ is positive. (For one of the two actual solutions, $\cos(x)$ is negative.) Then at a later step, squaring both sides introduces an extraneous solution. Then, when you take arcsin, you are missing the second branch of arcsin. This can all be saved though and the actual solutions are roughly $\arcsin(0.913)$ and $\pi-\arcsin(0.311)$.

Comment: Agree. Hand waving a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution, showing there are definitely two solutions and probably no others. It also indicates where the computational difficulty lies in providing a complete answer.

The equation can be rewritten as

$$1+2\sin x\cos x=\sin x+1-\cos^2x$$

which simplifies to

$$\cos^2x=\sin x(1-2\cos x)$$

or, on dividing each side by both $\cos x$ and $\sin x$,

$$\cot x=\sec x-2$$

If you now draw even a crude sketch of the cotangent and secant function (shifted down by $2$), you can see they intersect once in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$, once in the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$, and not at all in the interval $(\pi,3\pi/2)$. (That is, $\cot x$ decreases from $\infty$ to $0$ while $\sec x-2$ increases from $-1$ to $\infty$ in $(0,\pi/2)$, etc.)

The final interval, $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$ is trickier, because both curves are decreasing there. Using special values of trig functions at multiples of $\pi/4$ and $\pi/6$, you can limit any possible intersections to the interval $(5\pi/3,7\pi/4)$, since $\cot x$ decreases from $-1/\sqrt3\approx-.577$ to $-1$ on that interval while $\sec x-2$ decreases from $0$ to $1/\sqrt2-1\approx-.586$. The problem is, $-.586\lt-.577$, so we can't definitely say the curves don't intersect. Presumably computing at the midpoint, $x=41\pi/24$, would be enough to show the curves don't cross, but that seems like a lot of work; there ought to be a better way. (Drawing the graphs of $y=\cot x$ and $y=\sec x-2$ *carefully* will, of course, settle the matter, but that's a lot of work too! If you rely on a computer to do the work, you might as well just ask the computer to graph the curve $y=1+\sin2x-\sin x-\sin^2x$.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the tan-half-angle substitution ($t \rightarrow \tan\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$) to turn the equation into a polynomial.

$$ \begin{cases} 
  \sin(x)  = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \\
  \cos(x) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\
  x  =2 \tan^{-1}(t)
\end{cases} $$

Since $\sin(2 x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$ the expression is

$$ 1 + 2 \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} + \left( \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \right)^2 $$

or

$$ \left. \frac{2 t (3 t^2+2 t-1)}{(1+t^2)^2} = 1 \right\} (1+t^2)^2 -2 t ( 3 t^2+2 t-1) =0$$

This polynomial is of 4th order with two real solutions

> $$ \begin{cases} t = 0.647989325215799 & \rightarrow x = 2.82499129600076
>  \\
> t = 6.26423704911644 & \rightarrow x = 1.14992088410486
> \end{cases} $$